# Looping through JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, each

I have a bunch of JSON data that I'd like to output on a page. I've seen so many variations on how this could be setup (and can change it), I'm not sure this is the best way for what I'm doing, but it validates in a JSON linter.

```
{
    "data": {

      "typeA": [
        {
          "name":"Thing 1",
          "link":"#"
        },
        {
          "name":"Thing 2",
          "link":"#"
        }
      ],

      "typeB": [
        {
          "name":"Thing iii",
          "link":"#"
        }
      ],
      "typeC": [
        {
          "name":"Thing iv",
          "link":"#"
        }
      ]

    }
}
```

I've tried to have this JSON in its own .js file, but actually had more luck keeping it in the document (it's a one-pager site anyways) - by "*more luck*" I mean I had this *kind of* working when I only had typeA.

Later within a document ready I have the following jQuery - which when executed tells me that data is not defined.

```
$.each(data, function(i, v) {
    $('#output').append("<p><a href='" + v.link + "'>" + v.name + "</a></p>");
});
```

I'm sure I'm missing something big here! I'd love the following:

1. Some clues as to what I need to do to get this working at all - and ideally that I could output typeA into #Output, and typeB, and typeC elsewhere, like #Output2
2. Some definitions / terms to the stuff or parts at play here. I really don't know what I don't know here and would love to read up on this more!

Thanks

Comment: This is a subject that has been asked about a lot on stackoverflow, but I find that the slightest difference in the structure of JSON makes other examples not work for me. I'm also not familiar enough with JSON to have much luck Googling!

Comment: Where does `data` come from? The rest of this is (so far) irrelevant. Could you provide [an SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: The data is something I made - mostly as a way to try to learn JSON. The markup surrounding the 40 entries or so is likely to change a lot. 

Also, here's a SSCCE (love the acronymn): http://jsfiddle.net/fdJHc/ I have the JSON in a <script> tag. Not sure that's right.

Comment: First, that's not JSON in this context; it's just an object literal. Second, you haven't assigned that literal to a variable, which is the root of the problem. Slightly-working version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Q2qMZ/. Now you've got other issues to sort out. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This whole exercise is primarily for learning. Can you tell me how it would be legal? The "assigning it a variable" isn't enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case assuming `data` is the variable referencing to the above object, you need to iterate through `data.data` since the outer object has only one key called `data` which contains types.

Then the type values like `typeA` is again a array, so to access the value like `link` you need to access the first index of the array using `v[0].link`

You need to use

```
$.each(data.data, function(i, v) {
    $('#output').append("<p><a href='" + v[0].link + "'>" + v[0].name + "</a></p>");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pDsjp/)

Comment: Cool. So I was missing the "variable referencing the object". This nested array thing is a big light bulb... will play with this and checkmark you if this solves all of life's problems! Thanks! ;)

Comment: above code will just take first element only from inner array.

Answer (score 0):

Try beloe code

```
$(json['data']).each(function (index, value) {
        for (i in value) {
            $(value[i]).each(function (i, v) {
                alert(v['name']);
                alert(v['link']);
            });
        }
    })
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xppxZ/1/